# Vuetify - Dialog close / animation end handling

Tags: animation, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to detect when v-dialog component animation ends? I need to execute some code after closing dialog window, and I have to wait while the dialog dissapears.

Comment: Hmm I think similar question was asked for another component, but apparently you can't because it's CSS transition (depends on the component perhaps)? Likely it's fixed value like `0.3s`, so you can just presume it's 300ms. If it's vue transition then you might take a look at [vue transition hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks)

Comment: Thanks @Traxo, I have already tried vue transition hooks without any success. And yes, this is CSS transition. It could be good idea to listen something like 'animationend' event, but Vue, unlike to Angular, does not rendering component tag, and I do not have access to modal layout.

Also, I have tried to use solutions from similiar questions and I didn't got any result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback after dialog transition has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710212/callback-after-dialog-transition-has-finished)

Comment: Found the question, probably same. Apparently newer feature so perhaps you need a version update.

Comment: @Traxo thanks again; but I am using Vuetify 1.3.0.
Event 'transitionend' is called in v-navigation-drawer component, but not in v-dialog. So, maybe, the best solution is to use timeout.

Comment: I wanted to do this for `v-scroll-x-transition`, but it doesn't emit any events, so I'm going to try `vue2-transitions` package from npm instead, because it does support Vue transition events.